# Let $H$ have order $m$ and $K$ have order $n$, where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime. Then $H \cap K=\{e\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

> Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $G$. Let $H$ have order $m$ and $K$ have order $n$, where $m$ and $n$ are
> relatively prime. Then  $H \cap K=\{e\}$

My proof:

Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups where the $\text{ord}(H)=m$ and $\text{ord}(K)=n$ and $m,n$ are relatively prime. We know that $H \cap K$ is a subgroup of $H$ and $K$ since it contains the elements of both in $H$ and $K$. We shall let the $\text{ord}(H \cap K)=d$.

Then, by Lagrange's theorem, the order of $H$ is a multiple of the order of $H \cap K$. In other words, $m$ is a multiple of $d$ or $d|m$. Similarly,  by Lagrange's theorem, the order of $K$ is a multiple of the order of $H \cap K$. In other words, $n$ is a multiple of $d$ or $d|n$. Since $d$ divides both $m$ and $n$ and we know $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime then, the order of $H \cap K$ must be $1$.

Since $H \cap K$ is a subgroup, then by properties of subgroup, it contains an inverse which means it must also contain an identity and since $H \cap K$ contains one element, it must contain the identity. As a result, $H \cap K=\{e\}$

Hopefully, someone can confirm or correct any mistakes I made. Thanks!

Comment: It is correct, some of your expressions might be improved a bit though. For instance, at the very end, containing an identity isn't really an outcome of it being a subgroup rather than a necessity for it to be a subgroup. The point being you cannot define what an inverse is, if you don't have the identity in the first place...

Comment: That sounds better, thanks Theo!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We have that $ H \cap K \leqslant H \Rightarrow |H \cap K| \mid |H|$ (Lagrange) and similarly $ H \cap K \leqslant K \Rightarrow |H \cap K| \mid |K|.$ Hence $|H \cap K|$ is a common divisor of both $|H|$ and $|K|.$ Since $\gcd (|H|,|K|) = 1\Rightarrow |H \cap K | = 1 \Rightarrow H \cap K = \{1\}. \text {} \Box$

Comment: I like your notation better. I shall incorporate it in my proof. thanks.

Comment: No problem, there was a small error in my proof which I just fixed

Comment: I shall look it over.

Comment: What will happen if orders are not relative prime ?

Comment: @Bluey Then $| H \cap K| $ is not necessarily the identity.