# Let $G$ be a group of order $360$. Let $A$ and $B$ be its Sylow-$2$ and Sylow-$3$ subgroups. Find the order of $A\cap B$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

This is what i tried-

$\vert G \vert=2^33^25$. So,

$\vert A \vert=8$ and  $\vert B \vert=9$

Now let $a\in A \cap B$ then $ a\in A$ and $a \in B$. Using Lagrange's theorem this implies that $\vert a \vert \mid 8 $ and $\vert a \vert \mid 9 $. This implies that $\vert a \vert=1 $ and since $e$ is the only element whose order is 1, we have $A\cap B=\{e\}$. So $\vert A\cap B \vert=1$.

Please let me know if this is a correct conclusion.

Comment: Since $8$ and $9$ are relatively prime it follows from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227800/let-h-have-order-m-and-k-have-order-n-where-m-and-n-are-relatively?rq=1).

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct but because you are using Lagrange's Theorem which is result about cardinality of subgroup, it will be better if you consider $|A\cap B|$ rather than $|a|$. Of course your proof is not wrong because $|a|=|\langle a\rangle|$, where $\langle a\rangle$ is a subgroup.

Since $A\cap B$ is a subgroup of $A$ and $B$, by Lagrange's Theorem, $|A\cap B|$ divides $|A|$ and $|B|$ and hence divides $\gcd(|A|,|B|)$, which is 1 since $|A|$ and $|B|$ are relatively prime.
Hence $|A\cap B|=1$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Suppose If $|A|=8$ and $|B|=4$ then since $(8,4)=4$ and $|A\cap B| \mid 4$, can we conclude that $|A\cap B|=1$ or $2$ or $4$?

Comment: @RajkumarKumawat Yes